# Fibonacci series $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n!}x^n$

Tags: real-analysis

Let ${a_n}$ be a Fibonacci series $a_0=a_1=1$ and $a_{n+2}=a_n+a_{n+1}$ for every $n \geq 0$.

How is calculated the following limit  $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n!}x^n\;,\;x\in\mathbb{R}$$

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: It ia easy to see that the thing blows up as $x\to\infty$. Is something else intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can determine that the limit is infinite without actually evaluating the series, it’s not too hard to do the latter as well. We might as well set $a_0=0$; the desired function is then

$$g(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{a_nx^n}{n!}\;.$$

Differentiating twice, we find that

$$g'(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{a_{n+1}x^n}{n!}$$

and

$$g''(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{a_{n+2}x^n}{n!}\;.$$

But then

$$\begin{align*}
g''(x)&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{a_{n+2}x^n}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(a_n+a_{n+1})x^n}{n!}\\
&=g(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{a_nx^n}{n!}+g(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{a_{n+1}x^n}{n!}\\
&=g(x)+g'(x)\;,
\end{align*}$$

a differential equation that can be solved by standard methods. If $\varphi=\frac12(1+\sqrt5)$ and $\widehat\varphi=\frac12(1-\sqrt5)$, then

$$g(x)=\frac1{\sqrt5}\left(e^{\varphi x}-e^{\widehat\varphi x}\right)\;.\tag{1}$$

Now $\varphi>1$ and $|\widehat\varphi|<1$, so for large $x$ $(1)$ is dominated by the first term and blows up as $x\to\infty$.

The function $g$ is the *exponential generating function* of the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: very nice....... thanks Brian

Comment: @Horacio: You’re welcome.

Comment: I really dont understand why this answer is not accepted. It is a jewel of an answer. Some people are just rude...

Comment: @Horacio: It’s quite possible that the OP is off-line and hasn’t seen it yet.

Comment: It is quite possible too that the OP just dont value the help people offer him. For instance, he has only accepted half of the questions he has asked. You can see it in his profile. This is not fair for the people who takes time to answer him to help him.

Answer (score 3):

Since the $a_n$ are all at least 1, for $x \geq 0$ we have
$$
  \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n
  \geq \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{x^n}{n!}
  = \exp(x) - 1.
$$

Answer (score 2):

The exponential generating function for the Fibonacci numbers is given by
\begin{align}
S(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} F_{n} \, \frac{t^{n}}{n!} = \frac{e^{\alpha t} - e^{\beta t}}{\alpha - \beta}
\end{align}
where $2 \alpha = 1 + \sqrt{5}$ and $2 \beta = 1-\sqrt{5}$. As $t \rightarrow \infty$ it is easy to seen that $S(t) \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

the $n^{th}$ term of a fibonacci sequence is $A\alpha^n + B\beta^n$, so
$$
 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} F_{n} \, \frac{x^{n}}{n!} =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (A\alpha^n + B\beta^n) \, \frac{x^{n}}{n!} = A e^{\alpha x} + B e^{\beta x}
$$